# Cors error when i access to a JSON local file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ajax

i'm getting a error when i trying to access to a local JSON file. This is my function to bring the data from the json.

```
        $scope.getJSON = function () {
        (self.servicioObj = jsonFactory.GetJson('data.json')).then(
                function (dataResponse) {
                    $scope.datosJson = [];
                    $scope.datosJson = dataResponse.data;
                    self.servicioObj.detenerTiempo();
                }, function (error) {
            self.servicioObj.detenerTiempo();
        });
    }
```

And this is my Factory code.

```
    function jsonFactory($http, $q) {

    var self = this;

    self.urlBase = 'http://192.168.0.17:8383/NewFrontEnd/app/pages/';
    self.jsonFactory = {};
    self.tiempoEspera = 120000;
    self.jsonFactory.GetJson = function (metodo) {
        var tiempo = $q.defer();
        var url = self.urlBase + metodo;
        var peticion = $http({
            method: 'get',
            url: url,
            headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
            cache: false,
            timeout: tiempo.promise
        });
      return self.jsonFactory;
      }
```

When i call the getJSON function i get this error message.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.0.17:8383/NewFrontEnd/app/pages/data.json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8383' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I dont know why i'm getting this error if i put in the urlBase localhost instead of 192.168.0.17 i can access to the JSON file without any problem

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I dont know why i'm getting this error if i put in the urlBase localhost instead of 192.168.0.17 i can access to the JSON file without any problem

Comment: its to do with the browser protecting requests coming from a different origin than the resource requested

Comment: and how can i do solve it? i can't put the headers because im not trying to access to a backend server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why i'm getting this error if i put in the urlBase localhost instead of 192.168.0.17

Because `localhost` and `192.168.0.17` are different hostnames, so they are different origins.

If you load the HTML document on one and use XHR to request the other, you'll make a cross-origin request.

Either don't mix origins or configure the server to output the appropriate `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Comment: so i need to put localhost instead of 192.168.0.17? i need to because i need other users connect to my ip and access to the json file

Comment: You have three options. Either use `localhost` everywhere or use `192.168.0.17` everywhere or setup CORS on your server. You've dismissed option 1. Use one of the other two.

Comment: but its local json file of my project the JSON is not on the server side is there any solution for this?

Comment: If it isn't on the server, why are you requesting it using a URL that starts with `http://`?

Comment: im running the project in netbeans and when i run the project the url is http://localhost:8383 so i need to configurate the server of netbeans?

Comment: That or get a server which better reflects the environment you are going to deploy the project to.